# MySQL - Recursive - getting email addresses from 2 different tables and columns

Tags: mysql

I have a first table called **emails** with a list of all the emails of my colleagues

```
| email                    |
| -----------------------  |
| saramaia@email.com       |
| miguelferreira@email.com |
| joaosilva@email.com      |
| joanamaia@email.com      |
```

I have a second table called **aliases**, with a list of all the secondary emails/aliases my colleagues are using

```
| alias1                   | alias2              |
| ------------------------ | ------------------- |
| joanamaia@email.com      | maiajoana@email.com |
| maiajoana@email.com      | maia@email.com      |
| miguelferreira@email.com | miguel@email.com    |
| maia@email.com           | joana@email.com     |
| joanamaia@email.com      | jomaia@email.com    |
| joana@email.com          | jmaia@email.com     |
```

I can see that the users **joanamaia@email.com** and **miguelferreira@email.com** are using aliases. But let's focus on the user **joanamaia@email.com**.

I need to get a list of all the email addresses the user **joanamaia@email.com** is using. The difficult part is that I need to get a list with the main email address plus all the intersections where the first email and consecutive ones are being used by this user. The end result should look like this

```
| emails              |
| ------------------- |
| joanamaia@email.com |
| jomaia@email.com    |
| maiajoana@email.com |
| maia@email.com      |
| joana@email.com     |
| jmaia@email.com     |
```

If I do `WHERE email='joanamaia@email.com'` it should look like this, but I also need the same result if I do
`WHERE email='jmaia@email.com'`

I've been through some days of testing queries and I don't seem to have a solution for this (I've been using right joins, full outer joins and unions, but no luck so far). Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Can you please your database table and SQL that you have tried? Anyway, you can try to join query.

Comment: Is it to late to redesign these table in a vaguely sensible way

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, the table is really long, but I sure can redesign it in a better way.

Comment: Hi @MainulHasan,
I'm still working on it and I don't have a definite solution to this, but at this moment I think that maybe this is the most appropriate SQL to do this, but I don't think I'm in the right path to solve it:
`SELECT emails.email, aliases.alias1, aliases.alias2
from emails
left join aliases ON (aliases.alias1=emails.email)
WHERE emails.email='joanamaia@email.com'

UNION

SELECT emails.email, aliases.alias1, aliases.alias2
from emails
left join aliases ON (aliases.alias2=emails.email)
WHERE emails.email='joanamaia@email.com'

GROUP BY 1,2;`

Comment: Use recursive CTE and gather all dependent values. PS. First table seems to be excess in this puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to walk the graph and get the full list of interconnected aliases. Care needs to be taken to handle cycles; that requires the query to use `UNION` instead of the traditional `UNION ALL` to separate the anchor and recursive member of the CTE.

The query can take the form:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select 'joanamaia@email.com' as email
 union
  select case when a.alias1 = n.email then a.alias2 else a.alias1 end
  from n
  join aliases a on (a.alias1 = n.email or a.alias2 = n.email)
    and a.alias1 <> a.alias2
)
select * from n;
```

Result:

```
 email               
 ------------------- 
 joanamaia@email.com 
 maiajoana@email.com 
 jomaia@email.com    
 maia@email.com      
 joana@email.com     
 jmaia@email.com
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Q8pKF6D4H9fsiCjGynPtS/0).

Comment: this works very well. I wasn't aware of the recursive capabilities. thank you so much for spending your time with my question!